# Reading the results of me/accounts

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, json.net

I'm using the Facebook API for .NET, and need the access token for a page I'm the admin for.

I'm making the following call:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(tokens["access_token"]);

JsonObject jsonResponse = client.Get("me/accounts") as JsonObject;
```

Does anyone have a piece of script to read the values into a List or Dictionary for easy consumption?

Comment: avoid use of JsonObject or JsonArray use either IDictionary<string,object> or IList<object> instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually, this is the sample code in case anyone is interested. In this example, I'm retrieving the access_token field from the Page name set in the web.config

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);

        JsonObject jsonResponse = client.Get("me/accounts") as JsonObject;

        foreach (var account in (JsonArray)jsonResponse["data"])
        {
            string accountName = (string)(((JsonObject)account)["name"]);

            if (accountName == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageName"])
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["PageAccessToken"] = (string)(((JsonObject)account)["access_token"]);
                break;
            }
        }
```